# I want to create a special name in '' \declaretheorem ''

Tags: environments

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage{titlesec}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\titleformat{\section}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\thesection}{1.5em}{}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother




\usepackage{thmtools}




\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame]{definition}

\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition,style=mystyle]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}
\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{definition}

    {Soit $f\colon G \rightarrow G$ une application linéaire alors:%%%%%% <---------edit
   \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\]}
    \end{definition}
     \begin{proposition}
        Soit $f\colon G \myarrow[.7cm]G$ une application linéaire alors:%%%%%% <---------edit
    \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: for highlighting, indent your code by four spaces, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108171/how-do-i-get-code-to-show-up-with-color-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Your query is not very clear. What do you mean with ‘special name’? for which environment? B.t.w., when you insert some code, you make it visible selecting it and clicking on the icon with a pair of braces in the toolbar of the edit window.

Comment: Do you mean something like "Definition 1: (<Special Name here>) ......"? Then just follow the \begin{definition}[Special Name] .... That does that.

Comment: @Sango, for example \begin{props} hello \end{props}
result :
Propositions
hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correct, this might be the answer:

```latex
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame,name=la definitione]{definition}
```

(again) straight from the documentation... http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf (1.1 Elementary definitions)

> To save you from having to look up the name of the key every time, you can also use “title=” and “heading=”instead of “name=”; they do exactly the same and hopefully one of these will be easy to remember for you.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage{titlesec}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\titleformat{\section}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\thesection}{1.5em}{}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
    \thmt@trytwice{}{%
        \RequirePackage{framed}%
        \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
        \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
        \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
            \begin{framed}}%
            \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother




\usepackage{thmtools}




\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame,name=la definitione]{definition}

\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition,style=mystyle, name=el propo]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}
\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
        \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
        \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
        \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
        \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
            {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
        \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}


    \begin{definition}

        {Soit $f\colon G \rightarrow G$ une application linéaire alors:%%%%%% <---------edit
            \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\]}
    \end{definition}
    \begin{proposition}
        Soit $f\colon G \myarrow[.7cm]G$ une application linéaire alors:%%%%%% <---------edit
        \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

This:

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you